# How to custom VS code terminal?

Tags: fixed

I want to custom VS code terminal. but nothing happens when I follow it on the internet. Please help me. Thanks a lot

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
        "terminal.background":"#090300",
"terminal.foreground":"#A5A2A2",
"terminalCursor.background":"#A5A2A2",
"terminalCursor.foreground":"#A5A2A2",
"terminal.ansiBlack":"#090300",
"terminal.ansiBlue":"#01A0E4",
"terminal.ansiBrightBlack":"#5C5855",
"terminal.ansiBrightBlue":"#01A0E4",
"terminal.ansiBrightCyan":"#B5E4F4"`enter code here`,
"terminal.ansiBrightGreen":"#01A252",
"terminal.ansiBrightMagenta":"#A16A94",
"terminal.ansiBrightRed":"#DB2D20",
"terminal.ansiBrightWhite":"#F7F7F7",
"terminal.ansiBrightYellow":"#FDED02",
"terminal.ansiCyan":"#B5E4F4",
"terminal.ansiGreen":"#01A252",
"terminal.ansiMagenta":"#A16A94",
"terminal.ansiRed":"#DB2D20",
"terminal.ansiWhite":"#A5A2A2",
"terminal.ansiYellow":"#FDED02"
      }
```

Comment: Have you tried reloading vscode?

Comment: how to reload vscode in window? i am newbie

Comment: when i ctril + s is it just change background of teminal. Other thing like text color nothing happen

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to the settings (In VSCode obviously) On Windows/Linux - File > Preferences > Settings. On macOS - Code > Preferences > Settings. Shortcut (⌘,) Search (⇧⌘P) → “Preferences: Open Settings”
2. Search for "workbench: color customizations" and open the settings.json file.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to the settings in visual studio code.
2. On Windows/Linux – File > Preferences > Settings.
3. Search for “workbench: color customizations” and open the settings.json file under the User tab.
4. Edit or Paste your configuration under the workbench.colorCustomizations.